# In OIDC SSO scenario how do we maintain a session between the browser and many relaying parties (RP)/clients

Tags: session, openid-connect

Sorry if the question is too broad. There is a lot of information about the authentication process and everything to do to receive ID token from the Identity Provider (IdP). But after that step I find very little information. Is there a standard ways of using the ID token and how does the User maintain a session with many relaying parties? I can imagine the following scenarios:

1. I guess the most common sense scenario: Each RP always redirects to the IdP and if the end user (resource owner) already has active session with the IdP a new ID token is issued for this specific RP automatically. After that RP creates it's own session and gives the user a session ID that the user stores in the browser and can authenticate only with this RP alone.
2. I found this very nice article: https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#cool-id-token-uses where they mention stateless sessions, where you directly store the ID token in a cookie. But isn't this bad? From what I've gathered the ID token should not be shared with the User. Maybe issuing different JWT token that your cluster of RPs understand and can trust without going to the IdP?
3. All other solutions revolve around some central session store/cache in an RP cluster.

2 and 3 seems like creating a custom protocol just for session management with no real benefit and suggest one RP creating cookies for all the other, as they will probably be on different domain names. I will probably use pt. 1, but is there other good options?